# Can email addresses or phone numbers be exchanged over Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, rules, terms-of-service

When you have entered into a conversation with a person who asked a question, are you allowed to exchange email addresses or phone numbers? I apologize I did not know exactly how to tag this. I'm learning how to use this site I like it very much and want to be able to follow everyone's guidelines and policies.

Comment: Welcome! I'm glad you found us and are trying so hard to understand the system. One great way to learn how things work is by asking in a chat room. The people there really want to help you succeed. You need 20 rep, which you have on the [site](http://diy.stackexchange.com) where you've been spending the most time. I know first-hand that there are extremely smart and patient teachers in that room!! You can read about their chat [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). I hope you have a great time at Stack Exchange!

Comment: How do I get to my profile again so I can put my email address and everything on there so people that do want to contact me can do that and do so? And thank you all so much for your help! I cannot seem to get to it from the application is it easier to get to from the internet? As you can tell that question was a last minute thought! Lol

Answer (score 8):

#### Short answer

*Only in comments,* and since you don't have enough reputation on any site to post comments to other members, the really short answer is *no.*

#### Longer answer

We prefer that you didn't.  There are a number of reasons why.

1. Users who want to reveal their email addresses or phone numbers will usually put them in their profile, so you will find that information there, if it is available.
2. In general, we're not a clearinghouse for contact information, nor is our purpose to facilitate communication through other means.  We are a question and answer site, and we prefer to maintain that function exclusively.

Comment: Well I appreciate the answer. The only way to find out is to ask and I hope that this was the correct place to do so. Thanks again!! Goodnight

Comment: Further to point 2, we really want the resolution of the question to occur _on the site_ so that other people can use the information too. A comment that solicits you to solve the asker's problem elsewhere is flat-out bad. @user41750

Comment: Is there a reference for that policy in the answer?  I thought contact details could only be shared within user cards, and that even comments suggesting people should look there were borderline.  In other words if contact details are found in user cards, that's fine, but users need to look there off their own bat.

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: I think your Short answer says that I can make a Comment which says "send me an email using me@gmail.com".  Whereas my borderline case is a Comment saying "check my user card and send me an email".

Comment: @PolyGeo: Either way, the OP has insufficient rep.